# When running a custom TestEngine can execution of JUnitTestEngine be suppressed?

Tags: junit5, citrus-framework

I have created a custom TestEngine using the JUnit 5 (junit-platform-engine) framework.
The custom TestEngine registers using the ServiceLoader mechanism with an entry in META-INF/services/org.junit.platform.engine.TestEngine.
When I run my tests, this works well, but the tests get run a second time by the built-in JUnitTestEngine.
Is it possible to *replace* the default TestEngine in this circumstance instead of supplement it?

Comment: The JUnit platform provides filtering of test engines. The actual usage depends on the build tool you're using. Which one is it?
That said, building a test enginge that will run the same tests as another one is usually not a good idea. What is the purpose of the test engine in your sceanrio?

Comment: I want to run JUnit tests from inside a Spring Boot application. The idea is that this application can run autonomously, and periodically run a suite of tests and record the results. I used the ConsoleLauncher as a model, but don't need the command line arguments or the default reports.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer the question about the build tool. I'm using Maven.

Comment: It would have helped immensely if I had mentioned that I was using the integration between JUnit 5 and the Citrus Framework to run system tests. This explains why I want to run the tests from a Spring Boot app.

Answer (score 0):

After checking the JUnit 5 user guide and documentation for maven surefire plugin it seems there's currently no way to filter out certain test engine with Maven :-(.

Using the console launcher, however, does allow to choose test engines: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher-options. And so does Gradle: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle.

Comment: Thanks @johanneslink - that was the key insight. This led me back to addFilters in org.junit.platform.console.tasks.DiscoveryRequestCreator where filters are applied for included and excluded engines. In my launcher, I have an analog to this class, and by including my engine (and no others), it now runs only the one engine. Many thanks!

Comment: My guess is that if I knew more about the kind of test engine you want to build and how it's supposed to work, I could provide alternative suggestions for implementing it in a JUnit-platform-compatible way - or find out that the platform API is missing a useful concept.

Comment: Johannes, I'd be happy to answer any questions you may have. Thanks for your interest. My goal is to have a standalone application execute a suite of Citrus Framework system tests. Citrus integrates with JUnit 5, so I am using the JUnit Launcher API to run the test suite. I am capturing the test results using a TestReporter that is injected into each test method. Then the plan is to have the JUnit TestListener either write test results directly to a database or publish to an event stream for later processing.

Comment: I have checked in a skeleton project here: https://github.com/tvelkoff/system-test. The real thing runs tests; for some reason, this one can't find the sample test. But this should give an idea of what the launcher is doing.

Comment: After browsing your sample code online I still don’t understand why you need a test engine of your own in the first place when it’s doing the same thing the Jupiter engine does.

Comment: What's driving this is wanting to run this from a Spring Boot application. Ultimately it will be a periodic task. The Console Launcher is almost what I need, but at the top level it does a lot of handling of command line options. The DiscoveryRequestCreator (in the console) in particular mixes command line with configuration of the test plan. I have to introduce something similar that eventually will get the values of options from the application configuration, not the command line.

Comment: The Listener is not fully fleshed out but it will eventually write events either to a database or event stream such as Kafka.

Comment: This explains the use of `org.junit.platform.launcher.Launcher` but not why you need a test engine of your own. Point being: The only reason I currently see for your original problem to appear is when you want to subclass from Jupiter engine (or some classes contained therein) to adapt the way individual tests (or containers) are handled. For all other purposes `Launcher` and related interfaces seems to be all you need - with the additional benefit that all other test engines (junit4, jqwik, spock etc.) can also be used from within your `SystemTestRunner`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I will study the code very closely.

Comment: I clearly misunderstood the distinct purposes of the launcher and the engine. I have removed my extension of the Engine and all continues to work fine. Thanks for helping.